# Botón Reset no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, java, funciones, botón, function

Luego de una primera duda resuelta (¡gracias masterguru!), tengo otra que se generó a raíz del primer código.

En resumen son 2 botones con valores "10" y "5" los cuales al presionarlos, suma al total el valor correspondiente a cada uno y sin limites en la cantidad de clics.

Lo que no logro solucionar es que el botón "resetear", vuelva todos los valores a 0 correctamente.

Aparentemente si lo hace, pero al volver a jugar con los botones "10" y "5", hay valores erróneos en el total :(, lo que implica que no se resetearon correctamente los valores.

Comparto el código completo. Muchas Gracias por su ayuda!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sumar() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto").each(function() {
//    $
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
var count = 0
function funcion() {
  count++
  document.getElementById('bt').value = 10 * count
  sumar()
}

var count2 = 0
function funcion2() {
  count2++
  document.getElementById('bt2').value = 5 * count2
  sumar()
}


function resetear() {
  document.getElementById("spTotal").innerHTML = "0"
  count = 0;
  count2 = 0;

}

</script>

</head>

  <body>
    

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL:</td>
        <td><span id="spTotal">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <button class="monto" id="bt" onClick="funcion();">
      <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-right-icon.png" width="50" height="50" />suma 10
    </button>
    <br><br>
    
        <button class="monto" id="bt2" onClick="funcion2();">
      <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-right-icon.png" width="50" height="50" /> suma 5
    </button>
    
    <br>
    <br>

<button onclick="resetear()" class="button">RESETEAR</button>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno realmente si debugueas un poco te daras cuenta del error. Sin embargo ahi te dejo solucionado el problema

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sumar() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto").each(function() {
//    $
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
var count = 0
function funcion() {
  count++
  document.getElementById('bt').value = 10 * count
  sumar()
}

var count2 = 0
function funcion2() {
  count2++
  document.getElementById('bt2').value = 5 * count2
  sumar()
}


function resetear() {
  document.getElementById("spTotal").innerHTML = "0"
  count = 0;
  count2 = 0;
  document.getElementById('bt').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('bt2').value = 0;
}

</script>

</head>

  <body>
    

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL:</td>
        <td><span id="spTotal">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <button class="monto" id="bt" onClick="funcion();">
      <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-right-icon.png" width="50" height="50" />suma 10
    </button>
    <br><br>
    
        <button class="monto" id="bt2" onClick="funcion2();">
      <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-right-icon.png" width="50" height="50" /> suma 5
    </button>
    
    <br>
    <br>

<button onclick="resetear()" class="button">RESETEAR</button>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero te ayude. el problema es que al resetear debes resetear los valores de los botones ya que estaban quedando con un valor diferente a 0.

Comment: Excelente! funcionó perfecto!. La verdad estoy aprendiendo y se me van esos detalles :) Gracias por tu ayuda!